# ¿por qué no se acomoda en su lugar?

Tags: html5

tengo una tabla pequeña para que muestre registros y un nav para volver a la pagina principal, el nav, que en este caso dice 'volver', se situa en la parte superior a la tabla lo cual no se porque si esta acomodado bajo de la misma en el footer:
les dejo el codigo:

```html
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel=stylesheet href="estilo.css" type="text/css"/>
     <head>
      <title>FORMULARIO DE RECLAMO</title>
      <div id="logo">
       <table border=0>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <img src="logo.png" height="20" width="30">
         </td>
         <th>FAFAf</th>
         <td>
          <h3>Calle Mercado, Edificio América Nº 1535 of. 102 Zona Central.</h3>
          <h3>Telf.: 2200020-71521695</h3>
         </td>
       </table>
      </div>
      </br>
      <h1>FORMULARIO DE RECLAMO</h1>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
     </head>
     </br>
     </br>
     <body>
      
       //mostrar registro
       $query = "SELECT nroreclamo, nomreclamante, corelecrec, orirecdep, recpor FROM $tabla;";
       $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
      ?>
      <table id="tablaregistro" border='2'>
       <tr style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
        <td>Numero</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Correo</td>
        <td>Origen</td>
        <td>Recibido por</td>
       </tr>
      <?php
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['nroreclamo'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['nomreclamante'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['corelecrec'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['orirecdep'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['recpor'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
       }
       
       mysqli_free_result($result);
       mysqli_close($link); 
      ?>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      </br>
     </body>
     <FOOTER>
      <nav>
       <a href="index.html"><br/>Volver</a>
      </nav>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
     </FOOTER>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hola Criss, deberías compartir el código generado en lugar del PHP que lo genera, para que pueda verse el problema mejor en la pregunta (se puede ver, pero también hay mucho código y texto que es innecesario). Lee cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tú archivo sintácticamente está mal debe ser así:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel=stylesheet href="estilo.css" type="text/css"/>
<head>
    <title>FORMULARIO DE RECLAMO</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="logo">
      <table border=0>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <img src="logo.png" height="20" width="30">
              </td>
              <th>FAFAf</th>
              <td>
                  <h3>Calle Mercado, Edificio América Nº 1535 of. 102 Zona Central.</h3>
                  <h3>Telf.: 2200020-71521695</h3>
              </td>
      </table>
  </div>
  </br>
  <h1>FORMULARIO DE RECLAMO</h1>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <!--mostrar registro-->
      <?php
        $query = "SELECT nroreclamo, nomreclamante, corelecrec, orirecdep, recpor FROM $tabla;";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    ?>
    <table id="tablaregistro" border='2'>
        <tr style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
            <td>Numero</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Correo</td>
            <td>Origen</td>
            <td>Recibido por</td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['nroreclamo'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['nomreclamante'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['corelecrec'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['orirecdep'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['recpor'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close($link);
    ?>

  </table>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </br>
    <footer>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><br/>Volver</a>
        </nav>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El código que generas no es html válido, tienes etiquetas donde no deberían estar (por ejemplo: el `footer` no debería estar fuera el `body`) o tienes etiquetas que se abren pero no se cierran (como la tabla con la que tienes problemas). Esto va a causar que los navegadores intenten interpretar el código html de la mejor forma que puedan... que puede no ser la forma como esperas.

En este caso particular, sólo añadiendo la etiqueta `</table>` donde corresponde solucionará el problema, pero te recomendaría que pasaras tu código por el [validador de HTML del W3C](https://validator.w3.org/) para solucionar otros errores que puedan derivar en errores como el de la pregunta.

Aquí puedes ver tu código con el `</table>` añadido y con el enlace "Volver" debajo de la tabla como esperas:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel=stylesheet href="estilo.css" type="text/css"/>
     <head>
      <title>FORMULARIO DE RECLAMO</title>
      <div id="logo">
       <table border=0>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <img src="logo.png" height="20" width="30">
         </td>
         <th>FAFAf</th>
         <td>
          <h3>Calle Mercado, Edificio América Nº 1535 of. 102 Zona Central.</h3>
          <h3>Telf.: 2200020-71521695</h3>
         </td>
       </table>
      </div>
      </br>
      <h1>FORMULARIO DE RECLAMO</h1>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
     </head>
     </br>
     </br>
     <body>
      
       //mostrar registro
       $query = "SELECT nroreclamo, nomreclamante, corelecrec, orirecdep, recpor FROM $tabla;";
       $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
      ?>
      <table id="tablaregistro" border='2'>
       <tr style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
        <td>Numero</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Correo</td>
        <td>Origen</td>
        <td>Recibido por</td>
       </tr>
      <?php
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['nroreclamo'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['nomreclamante'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['corelecrec'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['orirecdep'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['recpor'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
       }
       
       mysqli_free_result($result);
       mysqli_close($link); 
      ?>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      </br>
     </body>
     <FOOTER>
      <nav>
       <a href="index.html"><br/>Volver</a>
      </nav>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
     </FOOTER>
    </html>
```

Comment: gracias ya lo solucione revisando bien la tabla no estaba cerrada, solo fue eso gracias